# Unexpected Identifier fix

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I dont understand what the error means. "Unexpected Identifier". It doesnt really give me any information on the error. I have gotten this error before and I know its probably an error in the code or the way I wrote it. Help please.

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/JavaScript">

   // Declare variables
   var cardCat;   // card category M=morning, A=afternoon, E=evening
   var userInput;   // user input of cards
   var morCard = 0;   // morning cards
   var aftCard = 0; // afternoon cards
   var eveCard = 0; // evening cards
   var BR = "</ br>"
   var ES = ""

   // welcome user, start loop, and ask for card category
   document.write("Welcome to Coffee Survey" +BR);
   cardCat = prompt("Enter the category of the batch (M, A, or E) or enter Q to quit: " + ES);
   userInput = prompt("Enter number of cards in the batch");
   // start loop
   while (cardCat != "Q") {
      if(cardCat == "M") 
       { morCard = morCard + userInput; }
      else if (cardCat == "A")
       { aftCard = aftCard + userInput; }
      else if (cardCat == "E")
      { eveCard = eveCard + userInput; }
     };
   // Display totals
   document.write("Total # of morning cards: " + morCard + BR);
   document.write("Total # of afternoon cards: " + aftCard +BR);
   document.write("Total # of evening cards: " + eveCard + BR);

   //End program
   document.write("Thank you for using Coffee Survey");
   </script>
   </body>
   </hmtl>
```

Comment: It seems not like javascript...

Comment: Its doesnt look like javascript it look like VBscript which is posted by you

Comment: lol well what is it then? Im learning javascript at GPTC and the book is Javascript

Answer (score 1):

javascript will be

```
while (cardCat != "Q") {
          document.write("Enter number of cards in the batch");
          if(cardCat == "M")
             {mornCard = mornCard + userInput; }
          else if(cardCat == "A")
              { aftCard = aftCard + userInput; }
          else if(cardCat == "E")
            { eveCard = eveCard + userInput }
         document.write("Enter category(M, A, or E) or enter Q to quit:);
};
```

Thing look wrong in your code is placment of `End If` so correct will be, this is VBSCRIPT not javascript

```
   // start loop
   while cardCat != "Q" {
      document.write("Enter number of cards in the batch");
      If cardCat == "M" Then
        mornCard = mornCard + userInput;
      Else If cardCat == "A" Then
        aftCard = aftCard + userInput;
      Else If cardCat == "E" Then
        eveCard = eveCard + userInput;
     End If'correctly placed end if which is wrong in your code
   } 

   document.write("Enter category(M, A, or E) or enter Q to quit:);
   End while
```

Comment: Better add `{` and `}` for each condition?

Comment: @fuyushimoya - i correct that i think i also found error